# Menu Navigation Item Disappearing from Menu in .rst Index File

Tags: indexing, restructuredtext

I'm experiencing an issue with my navigation menu. I'm trying to add the **getting_started** page to my existing toctree as follows:

[toctree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kup2M.png)

This is causing some unpredictable behavior on the front end. When I click certain items in the menu, the **Getting Started** item disappears from the menu, and when I click on others it remains. I don't see a pattern, so I'm confused.

In addition, I don't know what the **/index** syntax does, but I think it's related to this issue. I've tried removing it, but this just removes the respective items from the nav menu, so I've tried *adding* **/index** to **getting_started**, but that removes it from the menu entirely.

For example, the screenshot below shows the nav menu:

[Nav Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiyY0.png)

Firstly, notice that the nav menu item **Installing** is not displayed in the menu.

Secondly, regarding the strange behavior, notice that when I click Getting Started, the menu item Third Party Tools disappears from the nav menu.

[Third Party Tools Removed from Nav Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvtux.png)

This same sort of behavior persists when I click on other nav menu items.

It may be relevant to say that I did not build this menu, but inherited it from a previous employee.

My theme is **sphinx_rtd**.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `toctree` entries? An index is something else. What theme are you using? I've seen something similar in the Read the Docs theme where two or more files have the same name at different levels in the file system tree. We need to see a full file tree to help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code, instead of adding a comment which supports only inline formatting. Include your theme name and screenshots that illustrate the issue.

Comment: When you build the docs, do you see any warnings?

Comment: Hello, and thanks. Yes, I do, but I the only (potentially) relevant one says, "WARNING: document isn’t included in any toctree." However, I see that error in a) a number of places that are not related to the sections above, and b) are not preventing the correct functionality in those sections.

The other common errors say "WARNING: Title underline too short" and "WARNING: Literal block expected; none found".

Comment: Regarding "I've seen something similar in the Read the Docs theme where two or more files have the same name at different levels in the file system tree," the only files in my file system tree with identical names are index.rst files. Even though these files are located in different folders should they be unique? In our system the index.rst files include the toctrees.

Comment: Using multiple reserved file names, such as `glossary` and `gen_index`, can cause the problem I described. Can you create an example, per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Honestly, I would tear it down and start fresh, adding one file at a time until it breaks, or do the reverse by removing one file at a time until it succeeds.